# jquery success dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//codes
 success: function(html){

// this is for input box  - working
   document.getElementById('val').value='';
   $('#val').value='';

// how do i set it for dropdown box to reset after sucess?
   document.getElementById('val2').value='';
   $('#val2').value='';
  }
```

Once user submit dropdown box, i need it to reset to value="" but now it sticks with user option even after submitted.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#val2').empty();` and `document.getElementById("val2").options.length = 0;`?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#val').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("val2").options.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
success: function(html){
   $('#val').val('');

   $('#val2').find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
  }
```